# Remove MySQL rows using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Bit by bit I've been converting a PHP web app I'm working on to Jquery AJAX form submits.

The current one I'm working on is for removing table rows. I think it's a problem with my javascript, because it keeps doing a page refresh even with `return false;`. This was the problem with my form which creates an object, but thanks to some help from this site, I got that sorted and it now works fully.

Here's my javascript:

```
$("form#table_customer").submit(function() {
        var query_string = 'page=customer&rows=';

        $(":checked").each(function() {
            query_string += this.value + "-";
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/deletesql.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: query_string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#maincontent').load('inc/showObjects.php?o=customer');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The PHP file (deletesql.php) works with normal POST submits. But I just can't seem to get it working posting the data through ajax.

You can see it in context at http://www.sfyfe.com/studioadmin/index.php?i=customer

Comment: alert success data..to check whether its working or not

Comment: what is the final query running in ajax request .Did you check the query??

Comment: you know that `rows` will be something like `1-3-5-` with `-` at end .. ?

Comment: There is no such element `form#table_customer`.

Comment: Well, not yet until `$('#maincontent').load('inc/showObjects.php?o=customer');` has completed.

Comment: swapnesh - I've tried using alerts, but I can't even trigger one on the basic submission of the form. Sumit Neema - The string is exploded by the php script. Onchie, that #maincontent div is loaded on page load by a js call. The call in this script just refreshes the table on the hope that one row's just been deleted

Comment: do an alert(query_string); right after the each function. What are the results

Comment: @Scott Fyfe $('#maincontent').load() is asyncronous. The submit handler is registered before the element is inserted in the DOM. The .submit() has no effect while form#table_customer doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#maincontent').load('inc/showObjects.php?o=customer');
    ...
    // at this point form#table_customer doesn't exist yet in the DOM
    // so this binding a handler will give no effect
    $("form#table_customer").submit(function() {
           ....
    });
```

Try this instead:

```
 // make the load reusable

 function addDeleteHandler() {
     // handle the load event
     // attach the event handler everytime the content is loaded, 
     // and the form#table_customer is added to the dom
     $('#maincontent').load('inc/showObjects.php?o=customer', function() {
         $("form#table_customer").submit(function() {

             var query_string = 'page=customer&rows=';

             $('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                query_string += this.value + "-";
             });

             $.ajax({
                 url: "inc/deletesql.php",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: query_string,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data){
                   addDeleteHandler();
                 }
             });

             return false;
          });
      });
  }

  addDeleteHandler();
```

Comment: Perfect. The ajax function is now working, I've tested it with some alerts. But it's not submitting the data to the php file. I can manually enter the url to delete specific rows, but the jquery function wont submit it.

Comment: I noticed that you are calling $('#maincontent').load() not only once. You need to bind the submit handler every time you call $('#maincontent').load(). You can wrap it in a function like `addDeleteHandler(){...}` so you can make it reusable. Then, instead of calling `$('#maincontent').load('inc/showObjects.php?o=customer');` every time, you call `addDeleteHandler();`.

Comment: You can check if the ajax is really working in your Chrome browser, Developer Tools > Network

Comment: I'm so so sorry guys. The reason it wasn't working was that my PHP script was using $_GET instead of $_POST to retrieve the row values. Such a stupid mistake :S